# Raycasting through a custom camera projection matrix

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine, camera, projection

After modifying my main camera's projection matrix, the ScreenPointToRay method that use ray casting begin to fail, so the method which detect touched object use raycast fail too. Is there any way to use ScreenPointToRay method with a custom camera projection matrix?

Comment: I would suggest using the inverse projection matrix to manually find the points, but that wouldn't fix any of the built-in stuff. Are you interested in the manual solution, or are you only interested in ways that fix the built-in methods? (I looked around some on a proper method, but I only found other people having the same problem.) Also, if you post why you changed the view matrix maybe someone could suggest an alternative way to get the same result.

Comment: I want to make an affect like this: when camera on top, camera will set full orthographic matrix; then if move camera to front or left size camera will set full perspective matrix. This's my demo use custom matrix:
https://youtu.be/U1km79bXiwE
Do you have another way to make this effect?
If possible, can you post a demo code to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: [Here's a way to replicate it using a perspective camera](http://pastebin.com/id1VJwUc). It's the "dolly zoom" effect, accomplished with a tiny amount of trigonometry. It's not really an answer to the original question though, so I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you made a custom camera projection matrix, then you probably know where is the user pointing to, how about casting a ray yourself and not using the helper?

If you have a problem with translation of the cursor to world position, there is a good approximation - take four angles on approxiamtely the edges of your camera's viewpoint (top of the viewport horizontal center, left of the viewport vertical center etc.) and interpolate between them.